# PhpExcel - Add images from a php generator?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am wondering if it is possible to add image from a php generator with link like this? `parse/BarGen/generator.php?text=760000322300000939115260`

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploads/simple.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Source : https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Did you try it? Be **bold** ;)

Comment: I did, but as so $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg(), I followed some examples on that.

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got it ;]

Comment: Right on, glad to hear it. Thanks for the update, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- well is there a option to auto adjust the size of image to fit into cell or vice versa?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php and look for the word "center". You can further your research using "center automatically imagecreate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution

```
    function createImageFromFile($filename, $use_include_path = false, $context = null, &$info = null)
    {
      // try to detect image informations -> info is false if image was not readable or is no php supported image format (a  check for "is_readable" or fileextension is no longer needed)
      $info = array("image"=>getimagesize($filename));
      $info["image"] = getimagesize($filename);
      if($info["image"] === false) throw new InvalidArgumentException("\"".$filename."\" is not readable or no php supported format");
      else
      {
        // fetches fileconten from url and creates an image ressource by string data
        // if file is not readable or not supportet by imagecreate FALSE will be returnes as $imageRes
        $imageRes = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename, $use_include_path, $context));
        // export $http_response_header to have this info outside of this function
        if(isset($http_response_header)) $info["http"] = $http_response_header;
        return $imageRes;
      }
    }
       $gdImage = createImageFromFile('http://127.0.0.1:1234/dynexep/BarGen/generator.php?text=760000322300000939115260');
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```